# Can't install macOS over Pop!_OS / Ubuntu

Tags: macos, installation, macos-catalina

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64475042/macos-catalina-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working), I've installed Pop!_OS over macOS, which works fine so far.

However, I would like to try switching back to macOS, but I can't, because the internal SSD isn't recognized by the installer:

[image: screenshot]

But the installed OS boots just fine. It seems, that the SSD isn't initialized during the macOS setup. Is there anything I can do, to get the disk listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is simple:

You have to click on `View` and then enable `Show all devices`. Now, the internal SSD will be displayed and you can do, whatever you want (partition, install macOS, ...).